# Can't setOnItemClickListener ListView Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-listview

I have implemented a custom adapter in a ListView but when i try to use setOnItemClickListener the function does not work. I tried using a toast to notify me if the click respond but it did not work

Here is my activity and the adapter

```
class PasswordListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var dataSource: SavedPasswordDB

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_password_list)

        user = intent.getSerializableExtra("loggedUser") as User

        loadPasswords()

        btAddOpt.setOnClickListener {
            // ...
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        this.loadPasswords()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        this.loadPasswords()
    }

    internal class CustomAdapter(context: Context, data: List<SavedPassword>): ArrayAdapter<SavedPassword>(context, R.layout.activity_password_list, data) {
        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder", "SetTextI18n")
        private lateinit var dataSource: SavedPasswordDB

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false)

            val pwd = getItem(position)

            dataSource = SavedPasswordDB(context)

            inflater.tvTitle.text = pwd!!.fromTitle
            inflater.tvUser.text = "User: " + pwd.pwdUser
            inflater.tvCont.text = "Password: " + pwd.pwdContent
            inflater.tvOptLink.text = "Site link: " + pwd.optionalLink
            inflater.tvCreated.text = "Created At: " + pwd.createdAt


            inflater.btDeleteCurrent.setOnClickListener {
                // ...
            }

            return inflater
        }
    }

    private fun loadPasswords () {
        dataSource = SavedPasswordDB(this)

        var passwords = mutableListOf<SavedPassword>()

        val cursor = dataSource.selectPwdByUser(user.id)

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val col = SavedPassword(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getInt(6))
            passwords.add(col)
        }

        val adapter = CustomAdapter(this, passwords)
        lvPwds.adapter = adapter

        lvPwds.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, id ->
            val intent = Intent(this, PasswordDetailActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Also, i was thinking that the error could be in the XML files, maybe there is a property that im missging, so here they are:

ListView Activity:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvPwds"
    android:layout_width="353dp"
    android:layout_height="593dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btAddOpt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.87"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.90999997"
    android:src="@drawable/add_icon"/>
```

Custom Adapter:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/site"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvUser"
                    android:layout_width="61dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/userc"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOptLink"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/optional_link"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTitle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCont"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCreated"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:text="@string/created_at"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvUser"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvUser" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btDeleteCurrent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: May I ask why you need four different `linearlayouts` and a `listview`? I would maybe refactor this and use a Recyclerview. Not only is it easier, but more efficient too.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line to your ListViewtag in xml -

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

It will help you.